# How do I create and print a document (to a printer) using Gtk?

Tags: python, printing, gtk

I want to create a document and print it to a printer using my Gtk 3 app. I'm using Python 3. Here is the simplified code:

```py
import gi
import os

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")

from gi.repository import Gtk, Pango

parent = Gtk.Window()

printers = os.popen("lpstat -e").read().strip().split("\n")
print("Available printers: %s" % printers)

printcontext = Gtk.PrintContext()
context = printcontext.create_pango_context()
layout = Pango.Layout.new(context)
layout.set_text("Hello!")
printsettings = Gtk.PrintSettings()
print("Printing to: %s" % printers[0])

printsettings.set_printer(printers[0])
printsettings.set_print_pages(Gtk.PrintPages.ALL)
printoperation = Gtk.PrintOperation().new()
printoperation.set_print_settings(printsettings)
print("Printing result: %s" % 
printoperation.run(Gtk.PrintOperationAction.PRINT, parent))
```

but when I run it with the printer connected, it cancels the operation:

```
Available printers: ['Canon-MF210-Series', 'HP_Officejet_5740_series_434FB1_']
Printing to: Canon-MF210-Series
Printing result: <enum GTK_PRINT_OPERATION_RESULT_CANCEL of type Gtk.PrintOperationResult>
```

Why is it cancelling the PrintOperation with no error messages, and how can I get it to print properly? My system is an Ubuntu 20.04.2, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution! Using the `cups` module, you can get a list of the available printers, select one, and print a file to it! Here is an example:

```
import cups
import cupshelpers

# Create a new connection and the list of available printers
connection = cups.Connection()
printers = cupshelpers.getPrinters(connection)

# Select the first printer in the list...
for p in printers:
    if p is not None:
        printer = printers[p]
        break

# ...and print to it
printer.connection.printFile(
    p,
    "printer_test.txt",
    "Test this printer",
    {}
)
```

This can print several types of files, like PDF and plaintext. I'll update this answer if I find anything out about the `options` dictionary in the `printer.connection.printFile()` function. Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the `how to create a file with Gtk` question, but there are plenty of questions on how to create and edit PDFs.

Note: No guarantee that this works on Windows. If you have a Windows, you may want to look at [Brody Critchlow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9693927/brody-critchlow)'s answer.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use win32print?

All you would have to do is

```py
import os, sys, win32print

p = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name)
job = win32print.StartDocPrinter(p, 1, ("test of raw data", None, "RAW")) 

win32print.StartPagePrinter(p) 
win32print.WritePrinter(p, "data to print") 
win32print.EndPagePrinter(p)
```

Although if you need to use GTK, I think all the printing options are discontinued.

Reasoning:
[image]

**EDIT:**

The only valid printing operation on GTK's documentation is https://athenajc.gitbooks.io/python-gtk-3-api/content/gtk-group/gtkprintsettings.html

Comment: Is `win32print` a Windows-only option, or do I have to install it? Or is there a Linux equivalent?

Comment: Even though I solved the initial problem myself, you still get the bounty, because you helped me look somewhere other than `Gtk` for a printing module, and because you were the only one who was willing to answer my question! Happy coding!